# When are Ref's loaded when making a query in Datastore with Objectify?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

If I have a `@Load Ref<Driver>` in my entity Car and I make a query for Cars, when are those refs actually loaded from the datastore?

For example, in the code below are the Driver's loaded from the datastore when this query runs? Or are they loaded when I return the Cars at the end of my endpoint and it is serialized?

```
// The Query itself is Iterable
Query<Car> q = ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("vin >", "123456789");
for (Car car: q) {
    System.out.println(car.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `@Load` annotation, `Ref`s are loaded for each chunk of iteration. So if your chunk size is 30, then as each chunk of 30 cars is loaded their drivers will be loaded.

If you remove the `@Load` annotation, each `Ref` is loaded separately on demand.

Comment: @Micro, Can you please let us know if the above answer helps you?

Comment: By each iteration do you mean when you run the query and set a limit of 30 entities to be returned? Also, if you don't have @Load and you return the entities in an endpoint, will all of them then loaded from DS one by one during the serialization process?

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty Yes it did.

Comment: @Micro I mean each chunk. See the `ofy().load()...chunk()` method. By default, iterating a query works in chunks (of 30 IIRC). You can change the size. And Objectify doesn't know anything about serialization per-se; if/when your serializer calls the `Ref.get()` method, the value will be loaded (if it wasn't already loaded due to `@Load`).

Comment: I've never heard of the `chunk()` method. Is it explained somewhere in the objectify wiki? What I have been doing is just a query.

Comment: Not really mentioned in the wiki. It's mentioned in the Google datastore documentation and in the Objectify javadocs. There's always some notion of chunking in any unbounded stream. For the most part you can ignore it and accept the defaults.